# Partitioning problem in Kali Linux installation

Tags: linux, partition, windows, dual-boot, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali Linux dual boot with windows 8.1. During installation, only two partitiones:
[image]
 while I have 3 different partitions 
[image]
. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have GPT table and Kali can't manage them while installation. If you use `parted /dev/sda print` you'd see all of your partitions.

To fix it, you should wait Kali fixes its installer (or maybe there are some patch/tricks available, I don't know Kali)

Comment: I'm using Graphical Installation. Is there any other way?

Comment: @nAiN As I can see on the net, some people did the installation with GPT tables, but it's tricky and risky for your Windows installation. There are many things you have to do manually and may not work in your case...

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If it's only for testing purpose, I would install VirtualBox on your Windows then install Kali inside it as a guest.